# Golang and Gitlab continuous integration

Tags: docker, go, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am close to achieve a complete (without testing stage) continuous integration in **Gitlab** with a **Golang** software.

It fails when I am trying to build the Docker image at the `docker login` step.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  REGISTRY: registry.gitlab.com
  GO_PROJECT: mysoftware

build_golang_binary:
  image: golang:latest
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
    - cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
    - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
    - go get
  script:
    - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
    - go build

build_docker_image:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login $REGISTRY
    - docker build --no-cache -t ${REGISTRY}/me/${GO_PROJECT} .
    - docker push ${REGISTRY}/me/${GO_PROJECT}
```

Here is the error I am getting : `$ docker login $REGISTRY
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

I thought that the credentials would be provided into this CI process.. Apparently, they are not.

What is the best option to solve this ?

Comment: This is what works with our private gitlab instance; I assume it works for gitlab.com as well: `docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin $REGISTRY <<<"$CI_JOB_TOKEN"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer assumes you're using GitLab.com for both the CI and Registry (based on `registry.gitlab.com` being in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` example above.

You can utilize several environment variables available in the GitLab CI job to authenticate to the GitLab Registry:

- `docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY`

The `$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD` is an ephemeral token that is only valid for the duration of your job. You can learn more in [Authenticating to the Container Registry documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticating-to-the-container-registry).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was searching for ! I should find the list of available environment variables, that could help a lot...

Comment: I can help with that, too :) - [Predefined Environment Variables documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html). If this answer was helpful, please accept my answer.